# css3 multiple-column - which browser has the correct behaviour (if any)?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Here is a code, which was supposed to display 6 columns equally distributed across the container's width:
http://jsfiddle.net/fstyh/

BUT:
IE10 (*both pp2win7 and pp4win8*) and Opera 11.60 clump such columns together in weird manner (like region flow), while IE9, Firefox12 and Chrome17 just stack them one after another.

**Which browsers are correct ?** IE10 and Opera, because they are newer ? Or Chrome and Firefox, because they have bigger market share together ?

Before you answer, check what happens in Opera, when you add some text to those columns. (it's transparent, but works just fine to show effect).  IE10 does not react to it, in any way.

I was not able to find anything in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/). Hopefully, anyone can help.

Comment: "Chrome and Firefox, because they have bigger market share together ?" That doesn't make any sense o_O

Comment: The correctness of document rendering is not evaluated by a majority opinion or consensus, but by the specifications of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, it turns out that both mozilla and webkit still need vendor prefixes for multicolumn properties and values.

http://jsfiddle.net/fstyh/1/